# Today and yesterday I noticed new users who were able to access suggested edit reviews

Tags: support, reputation, review, suggested-edits, privileges

The first review queue one gets access to is first post and late answers at a rep of 500. How are some new users getting access to these reviews when they aren't global moderators and this is the only site they belong to? I didn't say anything yesterday since I thought this was a glitch but I have now seen it again. I can't remember the user from yesterday but the one from today is: [jon mark perry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210189/jon-mark-perry)

John Mark Perry is the only user depicted that is person for their avatar.

[image]

As you can see, they have earned the custodian badge as well.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps he reviewed suggested edits to his own posts. You seem quite concerned about this.

Comment: See also: [How the user with reputation <100 may get the “Custodian” badge?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/how-the-user-with-reputation-100-may-get-the-custodian-badge)

Comment: @user208259 it would be a concern if a new member was able to access review queues with limited knowledge of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All reviews are public. For example, [Jon Mark Perry's profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210189/jon-mark-perry?tab=activity&sort=reviews) shows he approved two edits, both to his own posts. (As user208259 predicted in a comment.)

Post owners can approve or reject edits to their posts regardless of reputation (and their vote is binding).

Comment: Obligatory shout out to the [MSE suggested edits faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) which includes the information from the second paragraph.